# apply an if condition in a sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

i want to use a if condition in a sql query according to following need.
"if a year field is null then do not calculate age and if it is set then it have to execute.
here is my query.where is the problem?please consider this scenario
'if month and date is there like for example 0000-03-12'

```
SELECT id, name, birth_date, birth_time, 
            city_native, country_native, sex, 
            city_current, country_current, image,
            if(YEAR(birth_date)='','',YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birth_date) - 
              (RIGHT(CURDATE(),5) < RIGHT(birth_date,5)),'') AS age
        FROM birth_user u
        WHERE <condition>;
```

Comment: Which DBMS are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [**IFNULL()**](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) to check birth_date is NULL

```
CASE WHEN IFNULL(birth_date,0)=0 THEN '' ELSE YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birth_date) END as age
```

Answer (score 0):

If your need is "if it is null", why are you comparing it to zero?

```
if(birth_date is null, 0, YEAR(CURDATE()) - ......) AS age
```

Where that `0` there is a suitable "default age".

Comment: because in my code if year is not available then set it to '0000' instead of 1970.

Comment: So it's not null, it's `0000-00-00`? In that case, why not just check `if( birth_date = '0000-00-00', ...)`?

Comment: but it will fail when there is month and date is there like for example 0000-03-12

Comment: Why would there ever be a month and date when the year is zero?

Comment: this is coming from facebook friend list friend,when a user does not allow to show a year feild.

Answer (score 0):

Use NULL instead of 0000

```
SELECT id, name, birth_date, birth_time, 
city_native, country_native, sex, 
city_current, country_current, image,
if(birth_date is null,'',YEAR(CURDATE()) - YEAR(birth_date) - 
(RIGHT(CURDATE(),5) < RIGHT(birth_date,5)),'') AS age
FROM birth_user u
WHERE " . implode(' AND ', $where);
```

Comment: in my code if year is not available then set it to '0000' instead of 1970.